# Completely Removing Tomahawk

Tags: 16.04, apt, uninstall, ppa

Tomahawk is now abandoned, though I didn't know when I downloaded it. I had some problems with it so I tried to uninstall it. Yet it's not removed with the remove or purge command (I can find it with the `apt-get locate tomahawk` command and it shows up in my Ubuntu Software store as installed).

It is causing an error every time I try to run `sudo apt-get update` (It has a ppa problem) and I want to remove both the app itself and the app from the update/upgrade scripts. How can I do this if remove commands don't seem to work?

Comment: how do you installed tomahawk? please tell us a detailed step by step on what did you do

Comment: @RenatoA. - I installed tomahawk from the Ubuntu Software center but I tried to remove it through the terminal.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get purge tomahawk --auto-remove` ?

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get purge tomahawk` and `sudo apt-get auto-remove`

Comment: well that's weird, have you tried to uninstall it from the software centre? you are not telling nothing of this in your question

Comment: Yes I tried that too. It looks like it will uninstall but then the buttons refresh and the options to open the app or uninstall appear again so it didn't work. Thanks for the help by the way! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61520/discussion-between-renato-a-and-symbio).